# How to figure out file path redirection for images using 301 redirection with htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having a weird redirection issue and can't figure out how to solve it. I installed my Wordpress in a directory (called /Cafe/ ) for my KatsCafe.org website and all the posts are being redirected just fine. But a huge number of my images are messed up. They won't redirect without the /Cafe/ in the URL, while none of my older URLs for images included a directory. My site is graphic/image heavy and many of them show up in Google Image searches so I am losing a lot of traffic over this.

I can't figure out how to redirect from two separate file paths to the current one. 
My oldest file path was from when I installed Wordpress in the root directory with a previous host, so image from that installation would have the file path:

```
Http://katscafe.org/wp-content/uploads/year/month/name-of-file
```

to the current image file path, which would be:

```
Http://katscafe.org/Cafe/wp-content/uploads/year/month/name-of-file
```

I have another less important redirection I am having a few errors from as well, stemming from the short while I tried out a multisite option (silly me, I thought I would enjoy not having to handle updates, etc ... but I'm entirely too OCD to enjoy that, LOL). Since that meant that my files were in a multi-site directory listing, the file path would have been:

```
Http://katscafe.org/files/year/month/name-of-file
```

and still needs to forward to the current image file path, which again, is:

```
Http://katscafe.org/Cafe/wp-content/uploads/year/month/name-of-file
```

I'm not sure if I am overlooking an obvious tool that can help me figure this out, but every tool I've found involves post redirection, not a file path type of redirection. And even then I'm not entirely sure of my ability to figure it out completely.

I would be forever grateful for any help with this! Thanks so much!

Comment: I finally found a reference, here on Stack overflow no less, that helped me solve this. This set of rewrite rules helped solve my problem. I found the reference post at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008678/htaccess-redirect-all-files-in-one-folder-to-exact-same-in-another-folder)